# Convert interval to microseconds as number type in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I know that for data type interval, one would use extract(epoch from interval) to get the length of the interval in seconds. The decimal precision of that seems to be 5, as I have a timestamp that goes all the way to the hundreds of nanoseconds in precision (truncated to microseconds when importing to table), but it returns 5 decimal places precision when I use extract(epoch) on it. So if I were to multiply the returned value of extract(epoch)by 1 million, I would only be getting precision to the tens of microseconds. Is there any functionality that can convert an interval to microseconds, or is multiplying the seconds my best option?

Comment: you can use `extract(microsecond from <interval>)` to get the microseconds

Comment: The PostgreSQL documentation for extract(microseconds) gives:

    SELECT EXTRACT(MICROSECONDS FROM TIME '17:12:28.5');
    Result: 28500000

This doesn't seem to be the length of the interval in microseconds, only the microseconds part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`extract` returns a [`double precision floating-point`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-FLOAT) which precision varies according to the platform.

> The double precision type typically has a range of around 1E-307 to 1E+308 with a precision of at least 15 digits.

```
select extract(epoch from now());
    date_part     
------------------
 1468585846.00179
```

> The extra_float_digits setting controls the number of extra significant digits included when a floating point value is converted to text for output

```
set extra_float_digits = 3;

select extract(epoch from now());
      date_part      
---------------------
 1468586127.88283896
```

`extra_float_digits` can be set at the session as above, at [database level](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-alterdatabase.html) or at [server level](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-EXTRA-FLOAT-DIGITS)

Comment: This looks promising, thanks! So I just have to do
    set extra_float_digits = 3;
before anything else and will that setting persist or do I have to reset it each time?

Comment: @Ben Updated with parameter setting

Comment: Much appreciated, this seems to be exactly what I'm looking for.