# How to cast an int of microseconds into a interval field in postgres?

Tags: postgresql

There is this question about [how to extract microseconds from an interval field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38387679/convert-interval-to-microseconds-as-number-type-in-postgresql)

I want to do the opposite, I want to create an interval from a numeric  microseconds. How would I do this?

The reason is I want to take a table of this format

```
 column_name |        data_type         
-------------+--------------------------
 id          | bigint
 date        | date
 duration    | numeric
```

and import it into a table like this

```
 column_name |        data_type         
-------------+--------------------------
 id          | integer
 date        | date
 duration    | interval
```

Currently I am trying:

```
select CAST(duration AS interval) from boboon.entries_entry;
```

which gives me:

```
ERROR:  cannot cast type numeric to interval
LINE 1: select CAST(duration AS interval) from boboon.entries_entry;
```

Comment: `make_interval(secs => duration/1000000.0)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do:

```
select duration * interval '1 microsecond'
```

This is how you convert any date part to an interval in Postgres.  Postgres supports microseconds, as well as more common units.

Answer (score 6):

you can append the units and then cast to interval

example:

```
select (123.1234 || ' seconds')::interval

outputs:
00:02:12.1234
```

valid units are the following (and their plural forms):

```
microsecond
millisecond
second
minute
hour
day
week
month
quarter
year
decade
century
millennium
```

Comment: I get `ERROR:  interval field value out of range: "21600000000 microseconds"` with `select (duration || ' microseconds')::interval from boboon.entries_entry;`

Comment: thanks for the comment. it seems postgresql can't convert to interval if the string contains a big number.